# How to mute audio speaker in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to mute audio speaker in android.
I tried

```
mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

and

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,true);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you need to know which stream you plan on hijacking, from what I've heard `AudioManager` is buggy. If your idea is to close all the existing streams and play only your sound, you could trick the other apps making noise by doing this:

```
AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

then remove it later by

```
AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL );
```

---

OR , you could mute it by changing the volume:

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
    AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: How about hijacking shutter sound in camera? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From Lollipop `setStreamSolo` was deprecated. There was another method in between, but now on Oreo, the right way to do this seems to be:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    am.requestAudioFocus(new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE)
              .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION).build()).build());
    am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

init:

```
var originalVolume = 0
private val audioManager: AudioManager by lazy {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return@lazy Util.appContext().getSystemService(AudioManager::class.java)
    } else {
        return@lazy Util.appContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    }

}
```

where need to mute:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
} else {
   originalVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0)
}
```

where need to unmute:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
} else {
      audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, originalVolume, 0)
      audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
}
```