# Programmatically muting a call in Android

Tags: android, audio, in-call

I am revisiting an old question posted (in early 2014 mind) here:

- [What permissions are needed to programmatically mute a phone call, from a background app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468064/what-permissions-are-needed-to-programmatically-mute-a-phone-call-from-a-backgr)
- [How to Mute Phone Call Stream (uplink) while calling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521394/how-to-mute-phone-call-stream-uplink-while-calling-on-android)
- [How to mute audio speaker in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884526/how-to-mute-audio-speaker-in-android)
- [How does setMicrophoneMute() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874881/how-does-setmicrophonemute-work)

For a recent project, I am building an app that can mute an existing call and get an audio recording from the user. I know that audio-recording in-call works, that's no problem (recording only the user mic). Now i can also reduce the volume programmatically, which i did using the code [On my Github, Here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemServices/Volume/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/volume/Volumizer.java)

Specifically, I am using the [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)) class to set the volume to 0 and also muting as a backup, but doesn't work.. I am wondering whether this is a Samsung specific issue or not..

```
mgr.setStreamVolume(stream, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mgr.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
boolean a = mgr.isVolumeFixed();
Log.d("MUTING", "Volume fixed: "+a);
boolean streamMuteStatus = mgr.isStreamMute(stream);
Log.d("MUTING", "Stream Mute Status: "+streamMuteStatus);
```

I am printing out the boolean variables above for testing purposes, but both print out 'False'.

But the Samsung S5 device is not allowing me to set the volume to 0 at all. This is true even when adjusting the in-call volume using the volume slider.. The slider does not physically move to the leftmost position on the seekbar. See figure below for the leftmost position i can drag to:

[image: The minimum position of the call volume seekbar]

Anyone have any ideas about how i can mute the incoming call stream?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem (both on a Pixel 2 phone and an Alcatel tablet). Did you find any way forward?